# Compressor is not working. Should I unplug the refrigerator for safety reasons?

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

Compressor is not working.  Should I unplug the refrigerator for safety reasons?

Comment: The answer is yes it should be unplugged. Have you tried unplugging and waiting a while and plugging back in? Sometimes after a cool down scroll compressors will restart and run for months occasionally but failure to start is the wake up that it needs service possibly a capacitor, possibly the compressor itself and even a damaged wire could be a cause if any appliance is not functioning it should be unplugged or power removed for safety.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely!  I cannot imagine why you would want to keep it plugged in anyway if it's not working.  All that can possibly do is cause more damage.